# Asignar rol a mi usuario actual en Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring, spring-security

Tengo la siguiente relacion entre mis tablas de usuario y rol M:M, pero tengo el problema que quiero que el rol sea dinámico, se que la entidad usuario_rol guarda la relacion segun sea cada rol, pero quiero que en el UsuarioController.java pueda ingresar desde postman el rol(autoridad) que quiero con el fin de crear un formulario de registro que se pueda elegir que roles puede tener dicho usuario, se me dificulta recuperar ese rol y no quiero que siempre se asigne un rol especifico asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Rol rol = new Rol();
rol.setIdRol(2L);
rol.setNombreRol("ASPIRANTE");
```

Dejo como postman lo guarda

```
{
    "idUsuario": 1,
    "username": "kriz",
    "password": "$2a$10$WXSVrQT3KTeyGpfymfY.rO.NTVtDY7ngCFuYRNwLj/TZVT4cDXbny",
    "emailUsuario": "raul@gmail.com",
    "tipoUsuario": 1,
    "enabled": true,
    "authorities": [
        {
            "authority": "ASPIRANTE"
        }
    ],
    "accountNonExpired": true,
    "credentialsNonExpired": true,
    "accountNonLocked": true
},
```

Cualquier ayuda lo agradecería

Entidad Usuario

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements UserDetails{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idUsuario;

private String username;
private String password;
private String emailUsuario;
private Integer tipoUsuario;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "usuario")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<UsuarioRol> usuarioRoles = new HashSet<>();

public Usuario() {
}

public Usuario(Long idUsuario, String username, String password, String emailUsuario, Integer tipoUsuario) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.emailUsuario = emailUsuario;
    this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
}

public Long getIdUsuario() {
    return idUsuario;
}

public void setIdUsuario(Long idUsuario) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Set<Authority> autoridades = new HashSet<>();
    this.usuarioRoles.forEach(usuarioRol -> {
        autoridades.add(new Authority(usuarioRol.getRol().getNombreRol()));
    });
    return autoridades;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmailUsuario() {
    return emailUsuario;
}

public void setEmailUsuario(String emailUsuario) {
    this.emailUsuario = emailUsuario;
}

public Integer getTipoUsuario() {
    return tipoUsuario;
}

public void setTipoUsuario(Integer tipoUsuario) {
    this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
}

public Set<UsuarioRol> getUsuarioRoles() {
    return usuarioRoles;
}

public void setUsuarioRoles(Set<UsuarioRol> usuarioRoles) {
    this.usuarioRoles = usuarioRoles;
}
}
```

Entidad Rol

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "rol")
public class Rol {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idRol;
private String nombreRol;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "rol")
private Set<UsuarioRol> usuarioRoles = new HashSet<>();

public Rol() {
}

public Rol(Long idRol, String nombreRol) {
    this.idRol = idRol;
    this.nombreRol = nombreRol;
}

public Long getIdRol() {
    return idRol;
}

public void setIdRol(Long idRol) {
    this.idRol = idRol;
}

public String getNombreRol() {
    return nombreRol;
}

public void setNombreRol(String nombreRol) {
    this.nombreRol = nombreRol;
}

public Set<UsuarioRol> getUsuarioRoles() {
    return usuarioRoles;
}

public void setUsuarioRoles(Set<UsuarioRol> usuarioRoles) {
    this.usuarioRoles = usuarioRoles;
}
}
```

UsuarioServiceImpl.java

```
@Override
    public Usuario guardarUsuario(Usuario usuario, Set<UsuarioRol> usuarioRoles) throws 
    Exception {
    Usuario usuarioLocal = usuarioRepository.findByUsername(usuario.getUsername());
    if (usuarioLocal != null){
        System.out.println("El usuario ya existe");
        throw new UsuarioFoundException("Usuario ya esta registrado");
    }
    else{
        for(UsuarioRol usuarioRol:usuarioRoles){
            rolRepository.save(usuarioRol.getRol());
        }
        usuario.getUsuarioRoles().addAll(usuarioRoles);
        usuarioLocal= usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
    }
    return usuarioLocal;
}
```

UsuarioController.java

```
    @PostMapping("/")
    public Usuario guardarUsuario(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) throws Exception{

    usuario.setPassword((this.bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(usuario.getPassword())));
    Set<UsuarioRol> usuarioRoles = new HashSet<>();

    Rol rol = new Rol();
    rol.setIdRol(2L);
    rol.setNombreRol("ASPIRANTE");
    
    UsuarioRol usuarioRol = new UsuarioRol();
    usuarioRol.setUsuario(usuario);
    usuarioRol.setRol(rol);

    usuarioRoles.add(usuarioRol);

    return usuarioService.guardarUsuario(usuario,usuarioRoles);
}
```